# react-bootstrap-table2 csv prevent export hidden columns

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

Using react-bootstrap-table2 how would I go about preventing exporting hidden columns in the csv export component? Currently my UI has the ability to hide columns using the built in column toggle feature in react-bootstrap-table2. However, by default csv will export all columns.

There seems to be a way to do this by row but not seeing anything for by column https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Export%20CSV&selectedStory=Only%20Export%20Filtered%2FSearched%20Rows&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this part about hiding columns](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Export%20CSV&selectedStory=Hide%20CSV%20Column&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel), you can simply add `csvExport: false` to the column you do not want to export and it will not be exported.

To do it dynamically, you could add a method that is called when a column is toggled (defined in the [ToggleList documentation](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/basic-column-toggle.html#customize-togglelist-component) which will manually set `csvExport` to true or false on the column that was toggled.

Comment: This would work if I knew which columns I wanted to hide/not export in advance. The columns are hidden by the user so editing the column meta would be strange to combine with the existing components. I'm hoping there is a built in feature or a way to work with the filters.